# Screen scraping with Java and X3270

Tags: java

I have been trying to use Java to connect to X3270 (actually, wc3270, since I'm working on a windows environment) and control it to access a mainframe, login, navigate a few screens and get the data returned from x3270's command "ascii" for further processing (like separating the needed fields).

Even if I can connect to x3270 and login into the server, I'm having trouble to reliably retrieve the screens from x3270 after sending a command, even using threads to read the socket continuously.

Can anyone tell me what I should be doing to get things right?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot more highly recommend [Jagacy 3270](http://www.jagacy.com/), a Java screen scraping library that's incredibly reliable and dead easy to use.  I had tried rolling my own, and also both IBM HATS and IBM Host on Demand, and found Jagacy to be easy, quick, lightweight, and already done for me.

A full license isn't cheap, but was worth it to us.

Comment: The problem is getting the company I work for to buy the license. I can expect it to happen sometime after I become president for the Latin America branch.

Comment: I gave an honest - and long - estimate for how long the code was going to take me for me to be *sure* it was right, given I had no experience with terminal emulation.  My bet was "4 weeks plus testing", which is long... but gave them solid justification to spend money on a license.  If you have to write from scratch, I'm wondering if source is available for anything that's done the same job before?

Comment: I had been using Jagacy 3270 for quite long time in the past, but right now it is unavailable. jagacy.com domain is down, there is no contact with the vendor/development team. It was a good library, but with no updates, it does not support the latest vesions of JDK and is blacklisted by security software.