# java runtime process exec

Tags: java, runtime, mainframe

i need to do a mainframe wrapper, the mainframe runs Music SP and it can be access by TN3270 terminal.

i use the terminal emulator x3270 and i need to connect with it in java. I tried with java run time:

```
public void init() {

    Process p = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("> Starting server...");

    try {
        // Execution of mainframe
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "C:\\Program Files\\wc3270\\wc3270.exe", null);
        // Capture I/O
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        out = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
        err = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("> OK!");
        // Connect/login/enter/tareas.c
        System.out.println("> Connecting to Music SP...");
        execute("connect XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX");
        enter();
        //p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("> OK!");
        enter();
        //p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("> Login...");
        execute("String(login)");
        enter();
        execute("String(pass)");
        enter();
        //p.waitFor();
        enter();
        System.out.println("> OK!");    
        System.out.println("> Start tareas.c...");
        execute("String(tareas.c)");
        enter();
        //p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("> OK!");    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        p.destroy();
    }
}

public void execute(String query) throws IOException {
    if (query != null) {
        out.write(query);
        out.flush();
    }
    if (!checkOK()) {
        System.out.println(">>> FAIL QUERY");
    }
}

public void enter() throws IOException {
    out.write("enter");
    out.flush();
    if (!checkOK()) {
        System.out.println(">>> FAIL ENTER");
    }
}

public boolean checkOK() {
    try {
        in.readLine();
        return in.readLine().contains("ok");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But when i execute i get:

```
> Starting server...
 OK!
 Connecting to Music SP...
 FAIL QUERY
 FAIL ENTER
 OK!
 FAIL ENTER
 Login...
 FAIL QUERY
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at Connection.enter(Connection.java:86)
    at Connection.init(Connection.java:57)
    at Connection.<init>(Connection.java:20)
    at Connection.main(Connection.java:102)
```

Where and what is the problem?

Other question, when i do a query, how i can wait to do other query? i need to wait between querys

thanks!!

Comment: looks like you can run scripts http://x3270.bgp.nu/x3270-script.html

Answer (score 0):

IOException can be the cause of these:

- Reading a network file and got disconnected.
- Reading a local file that was no longer available.
- Using some stream to read data and some other process closed the stream.
- Trying to read/write a file but don't have permission.
- Trying to write to a file but disk space was no longer available.
- There are many more examples, but these are the most common, in my experience.

In your case, as stated above, stream was closed.

Comment: but i dont close the stream, no? i cant see where is the problem (in the code)

Answer (score 0):

InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)

instead of using default charset, try specifying it

also see [Screen scraping with Java and X3270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212999/screen-scraping-with-java-and-x3270)